# R removes spaces in read.table

Tags: r, csv

I came across some surprising behavior today that doesn't seem right to me.  I have a CSV file with several columns, some numeric and some text.  One of my text columns contains extra spaces between some words. When I read this file into R using read.csv (or more generally read.table), it removes the extra spaces.  I am not talking about leading or trailing whitespace, but spaces inside the string.

I have looked through the docs and nowhere can I find an option to turn off this behavior.  Surely there must be a way to tell R to read the data as it is and not remove these spaces.   Or is there?

Comment: You will need to provide a reproducible example.  That behavior should not occur in `read.csv`.

Comment: examine: `print(read.table(text = '  some words  \t    some other words    ', sep = '\t'), quote = TRUE)`

Comment: My apologies.  The issue appears to be in RStudio rather than R itself.  In trying to construct an example I noticed this behavior.  If I load the data and print it to the console it works fine, but when I look in View() it is not fine.  This basically solves my problem since this won't affect my code, but does anyone know why this is?  Possible bug in RStudio?  I tried it in RGui and it works as expected.